# Counting carry operations

Tags: c

Can anybody tell me why my program keeps getting wrong answer? It must count the number of carry operations in a sum. I tried every testcase came to my mind. I didn't get wrong output.

Problem Description:

Children are taught to add multi-digit numbers from right-to-left one digit at a time. Many find the "carry" operation - in which a 1 is carried from one digit position to be added to the next - to be a significant challenge. Your job is to count the number of carry operations for each of a set of addition problems so that educators may assess their difficulty.

Input

Each line of input contains two unsigned integers less than 10 digits. The last line of input contains 0 0.

Output

For each line of input except the last you should compute and print the number of carry operations that would result from adding the two numbers, in the format shown below.

Sample Input

```
123 456
555 555
123 594
0 0
```

Sample Output

```
No carry operation.
3 carry operations.
1 carry operation.
```

Here's my current code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned long long int a,b,m,n,rem_m,rem_n,judge=0,sum,count;
    while((scanf("%llu%llu",&m,&n))==2)
    {
        if(m==0 && n==0)
        {
            break;
        }
        count=0;
        while(m!=0 && n!=0)
        {
            rem_m=m%10;
            rem_n=n%10;
            if(judge==1)
            {
                rem_m++;
            }
            sum = rem_m+rem_n;
            judge=0;
            if(sum>=10)
            {
                count++;
                judge++;
            }
            m=m/10;
            n=n/10;
        }
        if(count==0)
        {
            printf("No carry operation.\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%llu carry operations.\n",count);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem? not getting an answer for "0 0"?

Comment: when compiling, always enable all warnings (for gcc, at least: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`)  then fix the warnings.  for instance: for the posted code, the compiler will warn about unused variable 'a' and unused variable 'b'.   Strongly suggest placing each variable declaration on a separate line, for readability by us humans and for ease of documentation.

Comment: the code should have an appropriate prompt output at the beginning.  otherwise the user is left with nothing but a blinking cursor and no indication of what they should do next.

Comment: the variable `count` can never be greater than 10 so why make it a 'llu' variable?

Comment: the variable `judge` can never be other than 1 or 0, so why make it a 'llu' variable?   Also, the name `judge` is meaningless in the current context.  Suggest something meaningful like: `carry`

Comment: this code block: `            if(judge==1)
            {
                rem_m++;
            }
            sum = rem_m+rem_n;` can be simplified to: `
            sum = rem_m+rem_n+judge;`

Comment: testing of the code works fine, so what is the question?

Comment: since the criteria is numbers are less than 10 digits. each value input needs to be checked to assure it is <= 99999999

Answer (score 7):

> count the number of carry operations in a sum

Asserting a,b are >= 0:

### Terse solution

For fun :)

"ds" stands for digit sum.

```
int ds(int n){return n == 0 ? 0 : n%10 + ds(n/10);}
int numberOfCarryOperations(int a,int b){return (ds(a) + ds(b) - ds(a+b)) / 9;}
```

### Readable

Here is a more readable variation.

```
int digitSum(int n)
{
    int sum;
    for (sum=0; n > 0; sum+=n%10,n/=10);
    return sum;
}

int numberOfCarryOperations(int a,int b){
    // a, b >= 0
    return (digitSum(a) + digitSum(b) - digitSum(a+b)) / 9;
}
```

You can prove mathematically: every time you have a carry, the digitSum decreases by 9.

9, because we are in number system 10, so we "lose 10" on one digit if we have carry, and we gain +1 as the carry.

### Pythonic version

I do not know how to do this in C, but in python it is easy to write a better digitSum function. In python we can easily create the list of digits from a number, and then just use sum() on it to get digitSum of the given number.

Here is a terse python one-liner solution:

```
def numberOfCarryOperations(a, b):
    # f is the digitSum function
    f=lambda n:sum(map(int,str(n)));return(f(a)+f(b)-f(a+b))/9
```

Comment: wow - this is genius. took me several minutes to wrap my head around why this is working, but - wow. did you come with this yourself, or found it somewhere?

Comment: I am glad you like it. :) I have found it out myself. It is basically just math (not even high school) - I have some competitive math background (before collage). The problem came up as a TopTal challenge question: I could not solve it in time, I got angry and decided to figure out an elegant solution because I felt it is somewhere there. Ofc they did not accept later.:)

Comment: where this is a clean solution, it's probably less efficient than simply doing the long-addition and counting the carry operations. That's how I solved it in an interview, and then looked online to see if there's a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

The loop condition is wrong. You want `while(m!=0 || n!=0)` (i.e. *while at least one of them is not zero*) instead of `while(m!=0 && n!=0)`, otherwise the answer will be wrong for things like `999 9`, it will incorrectly stop after one iteration and report 1 carry operation whereas the correct answer should be 3. Think of it like this: you only want to stop when *both* of them are 0, so the loop must continue as long as at least one of the numbers is not 0.

Also, you forgot to clean up `judge` after printing output. You need to clear it before reading input again, or you could mistakenly have `judge == 1` from a previous computation that ended with a carry (the name choice for this variable seems odd to me, you should rename it to something more meaningful like `carry`, but it's not the main issue here).

`a` and `b` are unused (you should enable compiler warnings).

The sample output shows the word *operation* (as in, singular) when the count is 1; your program always writes *operations* (plural). If you're submitting this to an automatic judge, the code will not pass because the output does not match exactly the expected output. To fix that small little detail, replace this:

```
else
{
    printf("%llu carry operations.\n",count);
}
```

With:

```
else
{
    printf("%llu carry operation%s.\n",count, count > 1 ? "s" : "");
}
```

Here's the fixed version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned long long int m,n,rem_m,rem_n,judge=0,sum,count;
    while((scanf("%llu%llu",&m,&n))==2)
    {
        if(m==0 && n==0)
        {
            break;
        }
        count=0;

        /* We want || here, not && */
        while(m!=0 || n!=0)
        {
            rem_m=m%10;
            rem_n=n%10;
            if(judge==1)
            {
                rem_m++;
            }
            sum = rem_m+rem_n;
            judge=0;
            if(sum>=10)
            {
                count++;
                judge++;
            }
            m=m/10;
            n=n/10;
        }

        /* Clean up for next iteration */    
        judge = 0;

        if(count==0)
        {
            printf("No carry operation.\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%llu carry operations.\n",count);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Accepted ... Thanks for your Help... :)

Answer (score 1):

A ruby solution would be:

```
def count_carry_operations x, y
  return 0 if x == 0 && y == 0

  count = 0
  carry = 0

  while true
    return count if x == 0 && y == 0

    while x != 0 || y != 0
      xr = x % 10
      yr = y % 10

      xr += 1 if carry == 1

      sum = xr + yr
      carry = 0

      if sum >= 10
        count += 1
        carry += 1
      end

      x /= 10
      y /= 10
    end

    carry = 0
  end

  count
end
```

Answer (score -1):

A java solution would be:

```
public class Main {

    public  static int carry_count=0,carry_number=0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Carry(99511,512));
    }
    private  static  int Carry(int num1,int num2){
       if(num1/10==0 || num2/10==0){
           int sum=num1%10+num2%10+carry_number;
           if(sum>=10){
               carry_number=1;
               carry_count++;
               return Carry(num1/10,num2/10);
           }else{
           return carry_count;}
       }else {
           int sum=num1%10+num2%10+carry_number;
           if(sum>=10){
               carry_number=1;
               carry_count++;
           }else {
               carry_number=0;
           }
           return Carry(num1/10,num2/10);
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Java program for people interested

```
static int numberOfCarryOperations(int num1, int num2) {
        int counter = 0;
        int result1 = 0;
        int result2 = 0;
        int carryNum = 0;
        while(  num1 != 0 || num2 != 0) {
            result1 = num1%10;
            result2 = num2%10;
            
            if(num1 > 0 ) {
                num1 = num1/10;
            }
            if( num2 > 0) {
                num2 = num2/10;
            }
            
            if( (result1 + result2+carryNum) > 9 ) {
                counter++;
                carryNum = 1;
            } else {
                carryNum = 0;
            }
        }
        return counter;
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(numberOfCarryOperations(123, 456)); // 0
        System.out.println(numberOfCarryOperations(555, 555)); // 3
        System.out.println(numberOfCarryOperations(900, 11)); // 0
        System.out.println(numberOfCarryOperations(145, 55)); // 2
        System.out.println(numberOfCarryOperations(0, 0));// 0
        System.out.println(numberOfCarryOperations(1, 99999) );// 5
        System.out.println(numberOfCarryOperations(999045, 1055) );// 5
        System.out.println(numberOfCarryOperations(101, 809)); // 1
        System.out.println(numberOfCarryOperations(189, 209) );// 1
    }
```

Comment: This question is tagged for C. Please add an explanation to show exactly how this Java code helps the answer the question for the OP.